# How to deploy a config on a dedicated endpoint

Tags: marklogic

I'm playing with API/end-point configuration. I'm using the following call to PUT my config on the basic API (port 8000) :

```
curl -v -X PUT --digest --user muyser:**** -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "@config.json"  'http://example.com:8000/v1/config/query/myfirstconfig'
```

it works fine. Now I want to apply this same config to another end-point (port : 9037). this is an end-point that I created. It failed :

```
curl -v -X PUT --digest --user muyser:**** -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "@config.json"  'http://example.com:9037/v1/config/query/myfirstconfig'
```

Error :

> {"statusCode":500, "status":"Internal Server Error",
>   "messageCode":"INTERNAL ERROR",
>   "message":"XDMP-UPDATEFUNCTIONFROMQUERY: xdmp:apply(function() as
>   item()*) -- Cannot apply an update function from a query . See the
>   MarkLogic server error log for further detail."}}

Do you have any ideas ? I think, I forgot some options/features while configuring the enpdoint.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in version 8, if you create a REST API endpoint/extension that does updates, you have to annotate the function:

```
declare %rapi:transaction-mode("update") function my:endpoint(
  $context as map:map,
  $params as map:map,
  $input as document-node()*
) as document-node()?
{
  ...
};
```

I assume read-only is now the default for security reasons.

Comment: The change in V8 was just for POST; PUT and DELETE are still updates by default: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_52937

Comment: See the release notes as well: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap4#id_43559

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add a "modules" database to this end-point. it works now.